# Is there a tense for future perfect?

Tags: word-usage, tenses

Is there anything wrong with these sentences?

> Vorrò essere andato a scuola.
>
> Vorrò andare a scuola.

How do you render the future perfect tense in Italian?

Comment: The first does not exist (a double infinitive makes no sense, did you possibly mean "Vorrò essere andato a scuola" ?)

Comment: Yes verb to "be" or to have +past participle = perfect in english.

Comment: You already got replies to your question, but I would like to remark that the first sentence, even if correct, sounds weird to me. I am unable to imagine a situation in which it may sound appropriate.

Comment: @gd1: Let me see... “Adesso non mi importa niente della scuola, e non ci voglio andare di certo. Ma un giorno, quando avrò bisogno di un diploma, vorrò esserci andato”. Ok, not the most natural of sentences: I gave it a try.

Comment: @Dag: Excellent, I'm convinced!

Comment: @DaG: I would have said, "... avrei voluto esserci andato", and this is awkward anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is such a tense, and it is called in Italian *[futuro anteriore](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/futuro-anteriore_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/)*.

Comment: -1, this is not an answer, but, at best, a comment, though.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis: Would you consider it to be an answer now that I rephrased it to answer to the OP's question (“Is there a tense for future perfect?”)? As for “What's wrong...”, it was already answered by Martina, and edited in the question.